# ping in exec() not providing correct result

Tags: php, exec

When I'm trying to run the following script

```
$host = "ip here";
exec("/bin/ping -c2 -w2 $host", $outcome, $status); 
return print_r($outcome);
```

I see the following result

```
Array () 1
```

Any ideas as to why this could happen? I tried `ping` instead of `/bin/ping` to no avail

**UPDATE**

When running directly from SSH I'm getting shown the correct response thus being :

```
PING ip here 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip here : icmp_seq=1 ttl=243 time=4.47 ms
64 bytes from ip here : icmp_seq=2 ttl=243 time=4.40 ms

--- ip here ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.406/4.438/4.470/0.032 ms
```

Comment: What happens when you try the same from command-line? Does it work, or do you still get incorrect results (or no results)? If it's the latter, then it's a problem with the command itself (or the flags).

Comment: I have gone ahead and updated my question, thanks for notifying me about testing with command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try redirecting std_err to std_out by appending "2>&1" and see if it says anything that helps.

```
exec("/bin/ping -c2 -w2 $host 2>&1", $outcome, $status);
```

Depending on your configuration safe mode may only allow you to execute stuff in certain directories, or not at all.

See here: [php.net/function.exec](http://php.net/function.exec)

Comment: Thank worked, it produced the error I needed to fix, I needed to `chmod` after finding the error `Ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted`